# Importing Excel sheets in SSIS forces me to keep at least one sheet

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

When I build an SSIS package to import Excel spreadsheets in a folder by iterating through them, it seems that I have to keep at least one Excel spreadsheet to keep the Excel Source Data Flow Item.

It does not matter that the Foreach Loop Container iterator finds new spreadsheets which fit the schema that the Data Flow Item is aware of, the package simply will not compile in Visual Studio.

I currently find myself keeping a file named "KeepMe.xlsx" and use a C# script to pass the list of proper Excel sheets to import (meaning all of them but KeepMe.xlsx) to the Foreach Loop Container as a variable enumerator.

How can I bypass this painstaking step and keep the incoming folder empty, without having any issues running the package?

Also would this be only a compiler issue, meaning that once the package has been deployed, it would not throw the same exception? From what I remember, SSIS packages are always validated at execution time, or can this be overridden?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: How can you set a fixed filepath to your excel import task, when you loop through every file of a folder? To make it clear, you want to loop though different excel sheets, or excel files?

Comment: Different Excel files. I use a C# script to populate a variable enumerator which ignores the "KeepMe.xlsx" file. If I start with new files and do not keep that KeepMe file, then I get an error.

Comment: You can switch off validation on specific tasks. Right click the task, choose properties and validate is one of the options. Unfortunately I'm not at my PC so I can't be more specific.

Comment: You only need the file when first creating your data source because the column info is read. Unless you need to make changes, you can remove the file.

Comment: You are right about the validation issue. My expertise is now improved on SSIS and I would have found this by myself back then. If I knew then ... :) Thanks, though, it would help anyone with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

In the Connection Managers pane, select your Excel Connection.  Then in the Properties pane, change the DelayValidation property to True.

You will probably still need an example file to point to if you need to modify the inner data flow.  I just set that by editing a Variable value and using that for my Connection String.